# Rename files to a list with filenames

Tags: batch-file, powershell, cmd

I have a folder that have files like so:

> 11223.xml, 11223_2.xml, 11223_3.xml ...

The 1123 is constant, it can be any other pattern but for a given folder the pattern will be constant.

I have a txt file which has file names like so:

1. Index
2. about
3. home 
   ...

It's not necessary that the file names are numbered as shown but that doesn't matter either.

Is there a DOS command or a PowerShell way to rename the files in the folder to the name in the text file.
Currently I copy each file name, one at at time, from the text file and rename the file in the folder like so:

```
11223.xml = Index.xml
11223_2.xml = about.xml
```

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Rename which file to which name? Please provide a consistent example of input and desired result. Also show what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example it looks like you want the names of the existing files (in alphanumeric order) changed to the names in the input file in the order those've been put in there. If my assumption is correct, a PowerShell script like this should work:

```
[Collections.ArrayList]$newNames = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\newnames.txt'

Get-ChildItem 'C:\some\folder' | ? { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | sort Name | % {
  Rename-Item $_ ($newNames[0] + $_.Extension)
  $newNames.RemoveAt(0)
}
```

Note that for this to work you must have the same number of files in your folder as you have lines in your file.

Answer (score 0):

The Batch file below do the rename process you want. If there are more files than names, a standard name with increasing numbers is used. If there are more names, the additional names are not used. This program may be modified to include the number before each new name, if you wish.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set i=0
< fileNames.txt (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (1123*.xml) do (
      set "name="
      set /P name=
      if not defined name (
         set /A i+=1
         set name=noName_!i!
      )
      ren "%%a" "!name!.xml"
   )
)
```